# IE8 giving different window height to other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have some jQuery I use to determine if the user is at the bottom of the page:

```
 if ($(document).height() == $(window).height()
    && data.Info.TotalResults > $(".media-item").length) {
    Media.Search();
 }
```

In Chrome `$(document).height()` is 895 as is the `$(window).height()` yet in IE8 they are 895 and 891 respectively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a 2px border or margin around the body?

Comment: Possibly, as we use conditonal style sheets. Good shout

Comment: what about using `outerHeight()`

Comment: 'outerHeight()' returns the same

Comment: apparently so, several thread son the jQuery forum about it> Cheers for the replies, iull post answer if I find one